# Maven Proxy Authorization Required Error even after adding correct credentials to proxy

Tags: java, proxy, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.3.9. And I access the dependencies using proxy in Maven.

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>optional</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>name@organization.com</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <host>appropriatehostname</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
</proxies>
```

This was working great till yesterday. After that it stopped working at all. I neither changed any setting nor my password. Nothing.

Now, I have started using a workaround and I'm just using the username and removed `@organization.com`. Now with just the `username`, it is working. But my question is what happened the

> previous settings failed

without any reason at all.

Everyone else in my organization is able to connect and work with their `name@organization.com` as well as `name`. But it appears, it is just not working at all for me.

Comment: Difficult to troubleshoot such a case from outside. Did you try access the same proxy via, say, the browser, with the two different user names from your machine?